# How to place a custom placeholder in ngx-intl-tel-input before country selection

Tags: angular, intl-tel-input, ngx-international-phone-number

Need to have a placeholder like 'Office Phone' in 'ngx-intl-tel-input' before the country code selection and number input happens

```
<form #f="ngForm" [formGroup]="phoneForm">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ngx-intl-tel-input
        [cssClass]="'custom'"
        [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true"
        [enablePlaceholder]="true"
        [customPlaceholder]="Office Phone"
        [searchCountryFlag]="true"
        [searchCountryField]="[
          SearchCountryField.Iso2,
          SearchCountryField.Name
        ]"
        [selectFirstCountry]="false"
        [maxLength]="15"
        [phoneValidation]="true"
        [separateDialCode]="separateDialCode"
        [numberFormat]="PhoneNumberFormat.National"
        name="phone"
        formControlName="phone"
      >
      </ngx-intl-tel-input>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Trying to set it using below two fields but the still the input box looks empty

```
 [enablePlaceholder]="true"
 [customPlaceholder]="Office Phone"
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi1E1.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpLPF.png)

Currently using Angular 12.Kindly suggest if any other library could give the desired result.

Comment: I'm using Angular 12 and "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^3.2.0"
[enablePlaceholder]="true"
customPlaceholder="Mobile Number"
Placeholder without the property binding works for me.
Did you try this?

Comment: Thank you...Added the text as you mentioned it is working ,but when I select mobile number it doesn't replace the placeholder once selected.Do you have any stackblitz sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[enablePlaceholder]="true" 
customPlaceholder="Mobile Number"
```

Placeholder without the property binding works.

-
Credits to
@Fazeel Ashraf